# In NetSuite using SuiteTalk, Is it possible to create a CSV file from saved search

Tags: netsuite, file-transfer, suitescript, suitetalk, high-volume

Backgorund:
I am a newbie in the NetSuite world. We are trying to integrate NetSuite with our ERP and I am doing some preliminary research to find out what would be the best option moving ahead. The primary objective of the first task is to download huge volume of data from NetSuite to our end and find alternatives approaches.

I did some research on SuiteScript/SuiteTalk/Analytics and some facts I have come to find and my questions are below:

- Custom search can be created and save SuiteScript/SuiteTalk.
- This saved search can be invoked via both SuiteScript as well as SuiteTalks
- Well have a confusion, is the Saved Search the View, which SuiteAnalytics can access? (NOT MY MAIN QUESTION THOUGH!!).
- Using SuiteScript, return of Saved Search execution can be saved on as a flat file, and that file can be moved to File Cabinet. Exposing a REST API using RESTlet, this file can be downloded. [But have not implemented this yet!!]
- [MAIN QUESTION] **IS IT POSSIBLE TO DO THE SAME, CREATE A FLAT FILE AT NETSUITE END USING SUITTALK? AND ALSO HOW TO DO SAVE/MOVE THE FILE TO FILE CABINET AFTER THAT?**
- I have not researched more on the topic File Cabinet and how a created file or files here are indexed?
- Or Is it better to load whole result set from the SOAP call?

Your comments are highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly execute a saved search via SuiteTalk. You can also loop through all the results of the saved search and do whatever you'd like with those results, such as create a text file.

The SuiteTalk API also allows for accessing the File Cabinet to create or retrieve files, with limitations on file size.

Comment: Which API lets us access the file cabinet?

Comment: Just the normal "Add" method should work.

Answer (score 0):

Suitetalk can be used to create File and move file from a folder to another by changing the folder internalId of the fileObject.

Since you are using the Suitetalk to create/load Saved Search; you are required to create and save the CSV at your end using the search result and then move the file to file cabinet.

Since your objective is to get huge data from NetSuite I would recommend below option:

1. Use Scheduled script/Map Reduce to build a file and place it in required folder of file cabinet
2. Using Suitetalk you can extract that file. (Note: You don't need REST do this job. You can get the fileContents and store the result at your end. You cannot directly store the file. You will have to store the filecontents)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @netsuite-guru and @suite-resources!

So doing some further research, and considering your recommendations, the server side(at NETSUITE) scripting can be done only using  **SuiteScript to achieve the goal of automating - READ from NetSuite and WRITE to File to FILECABINET**!

Also found another good read thread as an option to MapReduce [link](https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/epic-battle-concurrent-map-reduce-vs-concurrent-suitelet/)

But would go with "Scheduled script/Map Reduce" at this time.